# Add a # as first character of lines in file that don't already begin with '#'

Tags: bash, sed

I am writing a simple shell script that will comment out any lines of code that aren't already commented out.  I am having trouble determining the correct conditional sed command.  The sed command to add a # to any file works but now I need to make it conditional so that I don't end up with two ## on lines that were already commented out.

I have been trying different sed commands but am new to Bash and cant figure out the cryptic looking syntax!

```
sed -i -e "/^#/! 's/^/#/' $file
```

The first part of the sed command is wrong. I am getting an error, and without the first part of the sed command all lines of the file will have a # added to it even if one already exists on that line.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How about `'s/^\([^#]\)/#\1/'`?  This says "if the first character is not a `#`, add a `#` before the first character".

Comment: You have an unclosed `"`. Please post a command that actually demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The command should work if you fix the quoting: `sed -i -e '/^#/!s/^/#/' $file`

Comment: This was asked and answered (again!) within the past week or 2. Just look in the archives.

Comment: "I am getting an error" - an important point about issue reporting is that you need to be specific. _What_ is the error?

Comment: It was an unexpected end of file error caused by the un-closed quotation mark.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the previous answers to close this as a dup of and no-one else has done it yet so here y'go:

```
$ cat file
foo
#bar
```

POSIX:

```
$ sed 's/^/#/; s/^##/#/' file
#foo
#bar

$ sed 's/^#\{0,1\}/#/' file
#foo
#bar

$ sed 's/^\([^#]\|$\)/#\1/' file
#foo
#bar
```

GNU:

```
$ sed 's/^#\?/#/' file
#foo
#bar
```

There are countless other alternatives...

Answer (score 0):

`awk` version

```
awk '{print (/^#/?"":"#")$0}' file
```